# Open local XAMPP site on iPad

Tags: ios, windows, ipad, xampp, local

How can I open my local XAMPP site and iPad?

I tried to open it like this:

```
http://192.168.3.132
```

But it keeps loading so I guess it does not work.

The IP is correct, I got it using `ipconfig` (Windows).

Comment: Are your iPad and the server under same subnet? Also check whether Windows firewall blocked XAMPP.

Comment: how can I check both?

Comment: First, make sure your iPad is under same subnet with the server (e.g. same router, same wireless access point). For checking firewall, you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209972/how-can-i-open-specific-port-numbers-in-windows-system